# Flutter PlatformException(error, The new embedding does not support the old FlutterView., null)

Tags: flutter, google-play-games

When running the app I get this title error, I use the play_games extension

Testing the app I realized that the popup of the Achivements were not shown, this error corrected at the beginning of the installation and configuration of the extension, I removed the line: await PlayGames.setPopupOptions();

As I realized that the notices for Scores and Achivements did not open, I decided to uncomment the line and now brings this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, The new embedding does not support the old FlutterView., null)
E/flutter (18824): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter (18824): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
E/flutter (18824): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18824): #2      PlayGames.setPopupOptions (package:play_games/play_games.dart:148:10)
E/flutter (18824): #3      GameServices.login (package:gamedabiblia/services/game.services.dart:21:20)
E/flutter (18824): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18824): #4      _HomeState._login (package:gamedabiblia/main.dart:80:34)
E/flutter (18824): #5      _HomeState.initState (package:gamedabiblia/main.dart:117:3)
...
```

My flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18363.592], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at C:\ProgramData\Flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (12 days ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\ProgramData\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\ProgramData\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\ProgramData\Android\android-studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\ProgramData\Android\android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.42.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have any solution to resolve this?